# Browser Search Transforms Elements

Tags: css

I have an transform:translate element insied an overflow:hidden element:

```
<div style="overflow: hidden; height: 200px; width: 200px;">
 <div class="hidden-element" style="transform: translate(300px, 300px)">Hidden</div>
</div>
```

And I have a hidden-element:hover { transform: translate(0px, 0px); } rule in the inner element.

When I perform Browser Search for "Hidden" (Ctrl+F) - the element is shifted to it's original position!

Why does it happen? How to prevent it? And why browser search change my layout in the first place?

Note I have no :focus css rule. Just hover.
This is happens in Chrome, Opera and IE. Not in Firefox.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a case of the element becoming visible, but of the containing div scrolling to reveal the newly selected content (which was only invisible before because it was outside the bounds of the containing div). You can see the behaviour more clearly in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fJ52f/1/ (CSS below)

```
#outer{
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    background:#FF0000;
}
#inner{
    transform: translateY(300px);
    -moz-transform: translateY(300px);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(300px);
}
```

I'm not aware of a way to prevent the scroll-on-focus behaviour of HTML, short of detecting the scroll event in JavaScript and forcing it back. But you could always just use `visibility:hidden` to hide your element instead of relying on hidden overflow content.

Comment: Helpful answer. visibility: hidden solved to problem. I didn't think about the scrolling explanation. Thanks!